# “My friend’s actual job involves a lot of work” or “The actual job of my friend involves a lot of work”

Tags: apostrophe

These two sentences have same meaning.
But my question is which one of them is more correct?

Comment: The second one is cumbersome.  There is some subtle difference in meanings between the two, depending on context.  The second is more likely than the first to mean that your friend is at his job already, but doing some side-tasks. (Whereas the first is more likely, for example, to be used when you are paying your friend with candy bars to fix a hole in your drywall, because you know he works in construction)

Comment: Justin I haven’t understood your explanation.

Comment: I'm sorry; I should have stuck around a little after I said that.  Just ignore my comment, mostly.  "Cumbersome" is like "unwieldy", or "awkward".  I'll put up a little answer in case it helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm an American English speaker. We use the word "actual" in a number of ways, along with different forms of the idea like "actually" or "actuality".  It is hard to understand what they do to a sentence.  I'll make a few examples

In these first two, "actual" means the single, specific one

> This is the actual guitar that Elvis used in Beach Blanket Bingo

> This is the actual coffee shop where my friend works.

Here I am saying something is genuine, and not fake.  It's the "real deal".  The guy asking is trying to be humorous, or is trying to "act cool"

> Q: Do you know what is more fun than mini golf?
>
> Listener: No, what?  What is more fun than mini golf?
>
> A: *Actual* golf.  The answer is actual golf.

To mean "This might surprise you, but..."
If someone thinks your friend works as an astronaut, but they are wrong, you might use this:

> Actually, my friend works in a coffee shop.

This is fine.  The speaker might be trying to correct a misunderstanding (that your friend is an astronaut)

> My friend actually works in a coffee shop.

> My friend works in a coffee shop, actually.

These words have a lot of uses in humor/comedy

This one is a way to sound dramatic:

> My mom thinks my friend works at a bar, but in actuality he does not.

This is even more dramatic/emphasized

> In all actuality, my friend works at a coffee bar.

Comment: Justin I appreciate your answer, I am following a book and I’m not a native english speaker, the book says the 2nd statement was correct, my question was not focused on the use of “actual” but on the use of apostrophe, for example it says- “He threw powder into the cashier’s eyes who was carrying a bag of currency notes” should be written like “He threw powder into the eyes of the cashier who was carrying a bag of currency notes”.

Comment: I understand.  It is somewhat subtle.  It isn't really about the use of an apostrophe.  It is okay to write *He threw powder into the cashier's eyes.  The cashier was carrying a bag of currency notes."  But in the incorrect example, the second part of the sentence is trying to specify which cashier is being talked about.  If the sentence were to continue, it would have to continue by talking about "eyes" - for example, "He threw powder into the cashier's eyes, which were blue."

Comment: The object is eyes, not cashier.  You can't specify which cashier at that point; you need a new sentence.  You can specify things about the eyes if you want, though, which might help.

Comment: Of the two, the first is better, more so without 'actual'.  I know we the Indians have a habit of using actual/ actually where it has no relevance at all.  They use it as a filler-word.